# Using Select Option forms with If statements in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

**My goal:**  To create a form that supplies different values per selection using Ruby/Rails form helpers with `if/elsif` statements to `show|hide` options. (Set working JS code in block quotes)

**My problem:**  Not sure how to use a option select values in **ruby/rails** with `if/elsif` statements.  This information will be entered into a `Post` from the user.  (using devise user gem)

**How I managed to get things sort of working:**
Created a bootstrap form with a JS function to show | hide option select fields depending on how they were selected. (Below my `_form.html.erb`)

In my Ruby Rails version of the form at the bottom, am I missing anything to hide the optional Hallway form initially? Is it constructed correctly in a rails format?

Forgive my lacking ruby rails syntax, as I am learning but cannot find a resource on how to perform a task like this to `show|hide` option select forms with `if/elsif` statements.

Thanks for your time ahead.

> **Explanation on how form operates:**
>
> Step 1: Select Grade Level
>
> Step 2: Select Hallway
>
> -*If Hallway A*, 
>         show Option select of Hallway A
>
> -*If Hallway B*, 
>         show Option select of Hallway B
>
> -*If Hallway C*, 
>         show Option select of Hallway C
>
> **My `_form.html.erb`:**
>
> ```
>   <div class="filter-third">
>     <div class="styled-select styled-blue">
>       <select id="post_gradelvl" name="post[gradelvl]">
>         <option value="%">Select Grade Level</option>
>         <option value="PS4">4</option>
>         <option value="PS5">5</option>
>       </select>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="filter-third">
>     <div class="styled-select styled-blue">
>       <select id="post_hallway" name="post[hallway]">
>         <option value="%">Select Hallway</option>
>         <option value="hallA">A</option>
>         <option value="hallB">B</option>
>         <option value="hallC">C</option>
>       </select>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="filter-third"id="hallwayAFields" style="display: none;">
>     <div class="styled-select styled-blue">
>       <select id="post_hallAClasses" name="post[hallAClasses]">
>         <option value="%">Select Available Classes</option>
>         <option value="hallAclass1">English</option>
>         <option value="hallAclass2">Spanish</option>
>         <option value="hallAclass3">German</option>
>       </select>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="filter-third"id="hallwayBFields" style="display: none;">
>     <div class="styled-select styled-blue">
>       <select id="post_hallBClasses" name="post[hallBClasses]">
>         <option value="%">Select Available Classes</option>
>         <option value="hallBclass1">Math</option>
>         <option value="hallBclass2">Science</option>
>         <option value="hallBclass3">Gym</option>
>       </select>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="filter-third"id="hallwayCFields" style="display: none;">
>     <div class="styled-select styled-blue">
>       <select id="post_hallCClasses" name="post[hallCClasses]">
>         <option value="%">Select Available Classes</option>
>         <option value="hallCclass1">Art</option>
>         <option value="hallCclass2">Extra Cred 1</option>
>         <option value="hallCclass3">Extra Cred 2</option>
>       </select>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> ```
>
> **My JS to have a `show|hide` option select for each Hallway:**
>
> ```
> <script>
>   $("#post_hallway").change(
>     function(){
>       if ($("#post_hallway").val() == "hallA") {
>         $("#hallwayAFields").show();
>       } else {
>         $("#hallwayAFields").hide();
>       }
>       if ($("#post_hallway").val() == "hallB") {
>         $("#hallwayBFields").show();
>       } else {
>         $("#hallwayBFields").hide();
>       }
>       if ($("#post_hallway").val() == "hallC") {
>         $("#hallwayCFields").show();
>       } else {
>         $("#hallwayCFields").hide();
>       }
>     }
>   );
> </script>
> ```

## My attempt at the Ruby Rails form version that is my goal:

```
      <div class="option-select">
        <%= f.option-select :gradelvl %>
          <select id="post_gradelvl" name="post[gradelvl]">
            <option value="%">Select Grade Level</option>
            <option value="PS4">4</option>
            <option value="PS5">5</option>
          </select>
      </div>

      <div class="option-select">
        <%= f.option-select :hallway %>
          <select id="post_hallway" name="post[hallway]">
            <option value="%">Select Hallway</option>
            <option value="hallA">A</option>
            <option value="hallB">B</option>
            <option value="hallC">C</option>
          </select>
      </div>

  <% if :hallAClasses %>

      <div class="filter-third" id="hallwayAFields">
        <%= f.option-select : hallAClasses %>
          <select id="post_hallAClasses" name="post[hallAClasses]">
            <option value="%">Select Available Classes</option>
            <option value="hallAclass1">English</option>
            <option value="hallAclass2">Spanish</option>
            <option value="hallAclass3">German</option>
          </select>
      </div>

<% elsif :hallBClasses %>

      <div class="filter-third"id="hallwayBFields">
        <%= f.option-select : hallBClasses %>
          <select id="post_hallBClasses" name="post[hallBClasses]">
            <option value="%">Select Available Classes</option>
            <option value="hallBclass1">Math</option>
            <option value="hallBclass2">Science</option>
            <option value="hallBclass3">Gym</option>
          </select>
      </div>

<% else :hallCClasses %>

      <div class="filter-third"id="hallwayCFields">
        <%= f.option-select : hallCClasses %>
          <select id="post_hallCClasses" name="post[hallCClasses]">
            <option value="%">Select Available Classes</option>
            <option value="hallCclass1">Art</option>
            <option value="hallCclass2">Extra Cred 1</option>
            <option value="hallCclass3">Extra Cred 2</option>
          </select>
      </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the syntax problems in your rails view, there is a more fundamental issue here: the view template generates a 'static' HTML page, which ONLY contains the select options for the hallway selected when the page is loaded. Your JavaScript won't work as there is nothing else to be displayed.

There is no way to do what you want without managing the show / hide in JavaScript. So, your rails view template will have to render the `select` for all hallways.

On top of that, if a user is editing an existing object, you will have to run your JavaScript right after the page has loaded, to hide what needs to be hidden immediately. Even better, everything should be hidden when you load the page, so the script will make visible only what needs to be there. Basically something like this:

```
updateVisibleClasses = function(){
  if ($("#post_hallway").val() == "hallA") {
    $("#hallwayAFields").show();
  } else {
    $("#hallwayAFields").hide();
  }
  if ($("#post_hallway").val() == "hallB") {
    $("#hallwayBFields").show();
  } else {
    $("#hallwayBFields").hide();
  }
  if ($("#post_hallway").val() == "hallC") {
    $("#hallwayCFields").show();
  } else {
    $("#hallwayCFields").hide();
  }
}

$(document).ready(updateVisibleClasses);
$("#post_hallway").change(updateVisibleClasses);
```

Rails can help you to generate the select statements, which should come from the server and not be hardcoded in the view. If you have a Class model, with a hallway attribute, you could generate the select options like so (this is just meant to be the starting point):

```
<%= form_for @name_of_your_model do |f| %>

  <!-- Take care of the grade level here -->

  <% @hallways.each do |hallway| %>
    <%= f.select 'hallway', 'class_id', Class.where(hallway_id: hallway.id).collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, { include_blank: true }) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Have a look at the [documentation for the select form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).